Using Apache Les Miserabeles Graph Chart How prevent nodes without links showing?
I Use the basis of chart  https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graph
For my version I need to be able to select a category on top and then I only want to show the nodes in that category that have a link attached to it. I need this because some of my nodes do not have a link based upon what category I choose.
Is this possible? If yes where in the folling code (html page) do i need to change things and how?
 <!--
    Knowledge Map v2
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
  <div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="echarts.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dom = document.getElementById('container');
    var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
      renderer: 'canvas',
      useDirtyRect: false
    });
    var app = {};
    var ROOT_PATH = '';
    var option;

    myChart.showLoading();
$.getJSON(ROOT_PATH + '/Graph_Data/KnowledgeMapData.json', function (graph) {
  myChart.hideLoading();
  option = {
    tooltip: {},
    legend: [
      {
        data: graph.categories.map(function (a) {
          return a.name;
        })
      }
    ],
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Aranea Knowledge Map',
        type: 'graph',
        layout: 'none',
        data: graph.nodes,
        links: graph.links,
        categories: graph.categories,
        roam: true,
        label: {
          show: true,
          position: 'right',
          formatter: '{b}'
        },
        labelLayout: {
          hideOverlap: true
        },
        scaleLimit: {
          min: 0.4,
          max: 2
        },
        lineStyle: {
          color: 'source',
          curveness: 0.1
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  myChart.setOption(option);
});

    if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
      myChart.setOption(option);
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);
  </script>
</body>
</html>



You can use the legendselectchanged event to modify the contents of your graph based on the selection. Here is an example for what you specified. The effect can only be seen for the one isolated node in category 'H'.
Example:
myChart.showLoading();
$.getJSON(ROOT_PATH + '/data/asset/data/les-miserables.json', function (graph) {
  myChart.hideLoading();
  graph.nodes.forEach(function (node) {
    node.label = {
      show: node.symbolSize > 30
    };
  });
  graph.links.splice(96, 1)
  option = {
    title: {
      text: 'Les Miserables',
      subtext: 'Default layout',
      top: 'bottom',
      left: 'right'
    },
    tooltip: {},
    legend: [
      {
        selector: [{type: 'all', title: 'All'}],
        data: graph.categories.map(function (a) {
          return a.name;
        })
      }
    ],
    animationDuration: 1500,
    animationEasingUpdate: 'quinticInOut',
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Les Miserables',
        type: 'graph',
        layout: 'none',
        data: graph.nodes,
        links: graph.links,
        categories: graph.categories,
        roam: true,
        label: {
          position: 'right',
          formatter: '{b}'
        },
        lineStyle: {
          color: 'source',
          curveness: 0.3
        },
        emphasis: {
          focus: 'adjacency',
          lineStyle: {
            width: 10
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  myChart.setOption(option);
  
  myChart.on('legendselectchanged', function(params) {
    const nodesWithLink = new Set();
    for (const link of graph.links) {
      nodesWithLink.add(link.source);
      nodesWithLink.add(link.target);
    }
    
    for (const node of graph.nodes) {
      if (!nodesWithLink.has(node.id)) {
        node.itemStyle = {color: 'transparent'};
      } else {
        node.itemStyle = undefined;
      }
    }
    
    const legendSelected = {A: false, B: false, C: false, D: false, E: false, F: false, G: false, H: false, I: false};
    legendSelected[params.name] = true;
    myChart.setOption({series: [{name: 'Les Miserables', data: graph.nodes}], legend: {selected: legendSelected}});
  });
  
  myChart.on('legendselectall', function(params) {
    for (const node of graph.nodes) {
      node.itemStyle = undefined;
    }
    
    myChart.setOption({series: [{name: 'Les Miserables', data: graph.nodes}]});
  });
});

